# Error (10822): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga

I cant find what i'm doing wrong, i would be glad if someone could help me on this...

```
entity fsmF is
  port(S, R : in  std_logic;
       Q    : out std_logic);
end;

architecture FSM_beh of fsmF is
begin
  process(S, R)
  begin
    if S = '0' then
      Q <= '0';
    else
      if (R'event and R = '1' and S = '1') then  -- <= ERROR
        Q <= '0';
      else
        Q <= '1';
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
end FSM_beh;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` part specifies an assign to `Q` based on the rising edge with `R'event
and R = '1'` (`rising_edge(R)`) and when `S = '1'`, which is OK.

The problem is that there is an `else` part assigns to `Q` when there is no
rising edge of R and S is '1'.  The `else` part requires a circuit that could
update on event of signals in the process sensitivity list, and then check on
other events than the rising edge, in order to assign to `Q` at these.

So keep the rising edge detection as separate condition, and other conditions
below, like:

```
if (R'event and R = '1') then  -- <= ERROR
  ...
end if;
```